# Can I add authentication (Bearer Token) to a link tag in the head to preload a data?

Tags: html, bearer-token, preload

I am trying to preload data in an application that uses the [TMDB API](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction)

The way I would like to preload it is using a [Link types: preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types/preload)

So something similar to this:

```html
<link 
    rel="preload"
    as="fetch"
    type="application/json"
    href="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list"
    crossorigin
/>
```

The issue is that the API seems to require a Bearer Token, or so I understand from the [official TMDB documentation](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/authentication)

Is it possible to add the authentication header to the link tag at the head of the document, or the outgoing request?

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<link>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-link-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Oh , I believe it's about backwards compatibility with some really old browser. But I do it cause I am use to it and it gets ignore by the browser :) still thanks for your input.

Comment: No. It's allowed for a time when it was thought XHTML--which is XML--was going to replace HTML. To disallow that slash could break thousands of sites. Otherwise it's entirely pointless and a waste.